# How can we run specs in separate environments using Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mocha.js, protractor

Is there a way we can run specs in different environments. Perhaps, any configuration in the protractor-config file?

Doing something like

`specs: ['../tests/*.js', server1],  ['../more_tests/*.js', server2]`

in the configuration.

Comment: You could have different configuration files

Comment: That's a good solution. But if we have several env then having multiple config files run in npm test with a ';' might not be good.

Comment: I guess there is a limitation on how protractor works. I did not find any reference. I have another issue. If I have a tree structure in tests folders. E.g. tests/component, tests/integration etc and test files inside them. How do I specify those here. protractor does not consider subfolders when I use: 
`specs: ['../tests/*']`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "separate environment". If you want to run different specs based on different capabilities, this is how:

```
    exports.config = {

      specs: [
        'basic/*' // specs to be shared amongst all capabilities
      ],

      multiCapabilities: [{
        'browserName': 'chrome', // You can specify version, etc
        // uses 'basic/*'
      }, {
        'browserName': 'chrome', // You can specify version, etc
        specs: 'basic2/*' // 'basic/*' and 'basic2/*'
      }, {
        'browserName': 'firefox', // You can specify version, etc
        specs: 'basic3/*' // 'basic/*' and 'basic3/*'
      }]
    };
```